# Storing SYSCALL functions in array of function pointers

Tags: c, macos, module, kernel, kernel-extension

I'm working on a project in which I have to hook 80%-90% of the system call functions on OSX (10.10.5). I'm doing this from a kernel extension. Since I have to (un)hook many functions, I want to store the original kernel function into an array of function pointers, to that I can do a quick lookup into the array in order to restore the original function upon unhooking.

```
    int (*kern_open)(struct proc *, struct open_args *, int *);
    int mon_open(struct proc *p, struct open_args *uap, int *retval) {
    kern_open = sysent[SYS_open].sy_call;
    sysent[SYS_open].sy_call = mon_open;
```

This works, the kern_open function is used to store the original kernel function that s called upon a system call. mon_open is my hooking function.

What I want to achieve is the following; so that upon unhooking, I can just iterate thru the KernSysCall array and restore the functions.

```
    // global array of function pointers that all have the same func def.
    static int (*KernSysCall[SYS_MAXSYSCALL])(struct proc *, struct args *, int *);
    KernSysCall[SYS_open] = sysent[SYS_open].sy_call;
    sysent[SYS_open].sy_call = mon_open;
```

Restoring: `sysent[SYS_open].sy_call = KernSysCall[SYS_open];`

However, storing the original kernel function inside the array of function pointers is causing a kernel panic. I haven't been able to attach the lldb yet, due to a `error: KDP_REATTACH failed` error. I'm hoping someone knows what is causing the kernel panic.

Below is a log of the kernel panic.

```
Anonymous UUID:       052D64D2-A43C-99F8-D221-B591991E54AF

Wed Nov 11 12:55:06 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80093f0024): Kernel trap at 0x0000000000000000, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x00000000769bb018, CR4: 0x00000000001606e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff80115e3fc0, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0xffffff80115e3fc0
RSP: 0xffffff8068dabaf8, RBP: 0xffffff8068dabf50, RSI: 0xffffff80115e3f80, RDI: 0xffffff8010059cf0
R8:  0xffffff7f8afaccdf, R9:  0xffffff8009ae2a18, R10: 0xffffff8009939740, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0xffffff8010059cf0, R13: 0x0000000000000005, R14: 0xffffff80115e3f80, R15: 0xffffff801188b480
RFL: 0x0000000000010282, RIP: 0x0000000000000000, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000010, Fault CPU: 0x0 VMM

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8068dab790 : 0xffffff80092e4ed1 mach_kernel : _panic + 0xd1
0xffffff8068dab810 : 0xffffff80093f0024 mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x664
0xffffff8068dab9e0 : 0xffffff800940de53 mach_kernel : trap_from_kernel + 0x26
0xffffff8068daba00 : 0x0 
0xffffff8068dabf50 : 0xffffff800982c0c1 mach_kernel : _unix_syscall64 + 0x2f1
0xffffff8068dabfb0 : 0xffffff800940e656 mach_kernel : _hndl_unix_scall64 + 0x16

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: xpcproxy
Boot args: debug=0x14e kext-dev-mode=1 -v keepsyms=1 kmem=1

Mac OS version:
14F27

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/DEVELOPMENT_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C75BDFDD-9F27-3694-BB80-73CF991C13D8
Kernel slide:     0x0000000009000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8009200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8009100000
System model name: VMware7,1 (Mac-66F35F19FE2A0D05)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 251264993940
last loaded kext at 249789197520: my.kext   1 (addr 0xffffff7f8afa9000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 116769666233: com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8aed3000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
my.kext 1

[more kexts here]
```

In request, the code for mon_open():

```
int
mon_open(struct proc *p, struct open_args *uap, int *r) {
    int error;
    char processname[MAXCOMLEN+1];
    char intercepted_path[MAXPATHLEN];

    pid_t pid = proc_pid(p);

    proc_name(pid, processname, sizeof(processname));

    size_t dummy = 0;
    error = copyinstr((void *)uap->path, (void *)intercepted_path, MAXPATHLEN, &dummy);
    if (!error) {
        printf("[MYKEXT] open called with path: %s, PID: %d, processname: %s\n", intercepted_path, pid, processname);
    }

    return kern_open(p, uap, r);
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: A reasonably well-written question! Are you sure it's the line `KernSysCall[SYS_open] = sysent[SYS_open].sy_call;` that causes the panic? (I assume `[SYS_open]` in the question was meant to be `sysent[SYS_open]`)

Comment: Thank you. That is correct. I am almost 100% sure. Declaring the static array does not cause the panic. Doing the same array thing with primitives (e.x. int) does not cause panic. Only when I assign `KernSysCall[SYS_open] = sysent[SYS_open].sy_call;` The rest is pretty much the same as the ugly "array-less" solution.

Comment: Note that DTrace also changes the sy_call of various sysent entries, so if anything in your system is using DTrace, it and your hook may be stepping on each others' toes. Is it crashing on *unloading* your kext, or do you unhook without unloading? Have you symbolicated your kernel panic to check exactly what's happening? (with a kernel argument of `keepsyms=1` the kernel will symbolicate the crash for you) To help you diagnose your LLDB failure, you're going to have to give us a bit more information on your setup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try `keepsyms=1`. I'm running it on a clean VM. No processes should be using DTrace. The hooking works fine with the upper method, but fails when storing them in the array. The lldb error I will have to investigate a bit deeper into myself, try it on another network.

Comment: @pmdj I've added the crashlog including syms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazingly stupid, I forgot to point `kern_open` (the return value of `mon_open`) to the function pointer in the array. `kern_open` was `NULL`, so this caused the `NULL`-pointer exception. Now the array of function pointers is working correctly.

@pmdj, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. Pleased to hear I wasn't completely barking up the wrong tree. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The 0x0 line in the panic log indicates that either a NULL function pointer is being called (more likely in this case) or you've smashed the stack and have overwritten a return pointer with NULL. Are you sure you're not "restoring" syscalls which you never hooked in the first place?

For getting lldb working with virtual machines, the requirements depend on the different virtualisation environments. With VMWare Fusion it should just work, assuming you're using 'host-only network' or bridged mode. With VirtualBox it only worked with the Virtio network device last time I tried, and I couldn't get it working at all on Parallels, but that was some years ago.

Note that if you add a serial port to your VM, writing to a text file, you can log to that using `kprintf()` - this may help you here as you can print out your pointer values when hooking and unhooking.

Comment: The panic is occurring when these are executed: `KernSysCall[SYS_open] = sysent[SYS_open].sy_call;
    sysent[SYS_open].sy_call = mon_open;`. I'm only "restoring" upon unloading of the kext. Since I do that manually, I know restoring is not causing the panic. Could it have to do something with wrong pointer dereferencing? (I'm kinda C-noob).

Comment: It's crashing because a process (xpcproxy) is making a syscall, and it's either calling a NULL function, or the function being called contains an error. What's the code for `mon_open`? (If you'd rather not post it, reduce it to something minimal that should still work, i.e. call through to the saved function ptr, then test that.) Your array declaration looks correct to me but it's hard to tell because C function pointer syntax is confusing. I'd `typedef` the function pointer type and then declare the array as an array of those types, just to be sure.

Comment: I've aded the code for mon_open(), but I highly doubt the issue is in that function, since the exact same function is used in the upper solution and working just fine. I have created a typedef: `typedef int (*kern_f)(struct proc *, struct args *, int *); static kern_f array[SYS_MAXSYSCALL];` and after that in another function: `array[SYS_open] = sysent[SYS_open].sy_call;`

Comment: Looking at the source for `unix_syscall64()` I'm now even more convinced that you're somehow writing `NULL` to a sy_call. I suspect the bug is in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: In a later kernel panic log `0xffffff808ae83f20 : 0xffffff7fab7b14b7 fox.grey-fox : _mon_open + 0x47` was added. I'm still struggling to get lldb working properly. `showallkmods` is giving me a `ValueError: Failed to read unsigned data. No value(type =No value) Error description: could not get SBValue: process must be stopped.` error.

Comment: Sounds like a kernel debug kit/kernel version mismatch.